How do I call a a method of a script on a condition which isn't attached to a gameobject without calling it from another script
This script's purpose is to increase the amount of enemies that are spawned after all of them are killed, my question is if there is anyway to call this script (like calling it via     [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)]) but on a condition, such as when the enemy count is zero. It's also necessary the method isn't static, because I need to be able to access the level variable.
I know this could be done by referencing it in any script that is attached to a gameObject, but that seems like poor code design to me, as why should a script made for player movement know about a script made for spawning enemies etc.
class EnemySpawning
{
    public int level = 1;

    public void Spawning()
    { 
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Game")
        {
            GameObject enemyObject = Resources.Load("BasicEnemy", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;

            int enemyQuantity = 3 * level;

            int minSpawnX = -3;
            int maxSpawnX = 3;
            int minSpawnY = 2;
            int maxSpawnY = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < enemyQuantity; i++)
            {
                int xPos = Convert.ToInt32(Mathf.Round(UnityEngine.Random.Range(minSpawnX, maxSpawnX)));
                int yPos = Convert.ToInt32(Mathf.Round(UnityEngine.Random.Range(minSpawnY, maxSpawnY)));

                GameObject.Instantiate(enemyObject, new Vector3(xPos, yPos), new Quaternion());
            }

            level += 1;
        }
    }
}


Spawning() isn't static, so an instance of EnemySpawning has to exist somewhere for you to call it. What's the reason for avoiding a MonoBehaviour for this?

You can have an event that gets called anytime an enemy dies to decouple your EnemySpawning class:
// Inside whatever class would be relevant to have this callback
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
  public static event Action<Enemy> EnemyKilled;
  
  // Example invocation of EnemyKilled
  public void Kill() {
    EnemyKilled?.Invoke(this);
  }
}

// The class that listens for the EnemyKilled event
public class EnemySpawning {

  private int aliveEnemies;

  public EnemySpawning() {
    // Since you're not using a MonoBehaviour for this, we have to use the constructor...
    // Tell Unity to longer call OnEnemyKilled whenever the EnemyKilled event is triggered
    Enemy.EnemyKilled += OnEnemyKilled;
  }
  
  public ~EnemySpawning() {
    // Since you're not using a MonoBehaviour for this, we have to use the destructor...
    // Tell Unity to no longer call OnEnemyKilled, since this class was destroyed.
    Enemy.EnemyKilled -= OnEnemyKilled;
  }

  public void OnEnemyKilled(Enemy enemyThatDied) {
    // If we run out of alive enemies, spawn another.
    if (--aliveEnemies <= 0) {
      Spawning();
    }
  }

  public void Spawning() {
    ...
    // Make sure to add so we keep track of the alive enemies
    aliveEnemies = 3 * level;
  }
}

This way you can just call enemy.Kill(), and the will EnemySpawning know that one died without coupling your Player or Enemy class to your EnemySpawning class
